# Angular bootstrap scope on screen size change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

My angular elements on different screen size sharing the same controller. Why when I modify my `select` `options` on small screen size (`SM`) and when shrink screen to extra small (`XS`) all changes has been lost?

I have two separate `HTML` files in order to keep each file smaller and more structured. Since my design for tablet and phones might be very different.

What should I do in order to keep my changes while switching between different screen sizes?

Thanks for any help!

index.html

SM.html

```
    <div ng-controller="PassengerController as pd">

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMFrom12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="adults" ng-model="adults" ng-options="value as value for value in adultValues" class="form-control" id="selectSMFrom12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMUnder12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="childrenUnder12" ng-model="childrenUnder12" ng-options="value as value for value in childrenUnder12Values" class="form-control" id="selectSMUnder12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMInfants">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="infantsUnder2" ng-model="infantsUnder2" ng-options="value as value for value in infantsUnder2Values" class="form-control" id="selectSMInfants"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

XS.html

```
    <div ng-controller="PassengerController as pd">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectXSFrom12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="adults" ng-model="adults" ng-options="value as value for value in adultValues" class="form-control" id="selectXSFrom12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectXSUnder12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="childrenUnder12" ng-model="childrenUnder12" ng-options="value as value for value in childrenUnder12Values" class="form-control" id="selectXSUnder12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectXSInfants">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="infantsUnder2" ng-model="infantsUnder2" ng-options="value as value for value in infantsUnder2Values" class="form-control" id="selectXSInfants"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myModule");



app.controller('PassengerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


    $scope.adults = 1;
    $scope.childrenUnder12 = 0;
    $scope.infantsUnder2 = 0;


    $scope.adultValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $scope.childrenUnder12Values = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    $scope.infantsUnder2Values = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];



}]);

var app = angular.module("fridayFly", ['ui.bootstrap']);


app.directive('searchBarSm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/SM.html'
    };
});

app.directive('searchBarXs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search-bar/XS.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: How do you switch between the html files?

Comment: Ori Drori, I am switching between html files by resizing my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be changing views when re-sizing,  just to apply different classes. You should add the classes you need. You're using bootstrap so should be like this:

`<div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">`

You only need the one view. Now, as you change screen sizes the class & style sheet takes care of the rest.

so in your case, you need just the one:

```
    <div ng-controller="PassengerController as pd">    
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMFrom12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="adults" ng-model="adults" ng-options="value as value for value in adultValues" class="form-control" id="selectSMFrom12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMUnder12">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="childrenUnder12" ng-model="childrenUnder12" ng-options="value as value for value in childrenUnder12Values" class="form-control" id="selectSMUnder12"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="selectSMInfants">12+ years</label>
                <select ng-init="infantsUnder2" ng-model="infantsUnder2" ng-options="value as value for value in infantsUnder2Values" class="form-control" id="selectSMInfants"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can reuse the same html but I made that on purpose in order to keep each file smaller and more structured. Since my design for tablet and phones might be very different.

Comment: So you want to duplicate all of your templates, to save using the bootstrap styles correctly? That is a very bad idea. You have, in this one instance duplicated EVERYthing and changed only 2 letters. Just because each file is smaller, it doesn't mean you're doing it right :)

Comment: Also, as you're finding out here, you have multiple templates each with it's own version of the controller. so you would have to hack something SUPER complex in order to accomplish what you're after - vs using bootstrap correctly and applying the styles you want :)

Comment: Oh - and also, just to note. If you're worried about phone vs tablet. Then you shouldn't be changing templates based on a screen resize. Phone is phone tablet is tablet. Load the views you need for that device. Not based on a screen resize.

Comment: Thanks, Darren - make sense now, I think you are right. What do you mean by "Load the view you need for that device"? I thought grid system is designed specially for that purpose: xs - for mobiles and sm for tablets. I am wrong?

Comment: The grid system is designed for just that yes - for when you resize a browser window. Though you said {quote}design for tablet and phones might be very different.{quote} - so this would imply if you're loading in a phone you want to load a template that would only be displayed on a phone. Same for tablet. You wouldn't/couldn't resize a tablet browser window (other than rotating). So. All that's to say. Use the idea in my answer for 95% of what you need. and where some templates are very different between phone & tablet, then load a specific template for that device. make sense?

Comment: Make sense, how do I load a specific separate template for specific device on the fly?

Comment: That's a different question altogether. You would need to provide info on your server-side setup. For this project I'm on, for example, my views are being served by ASP.Net MVC and I've used 51Degrees to determine what device is calling, and served the appropriate file, containing templates for that device.

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot Darren!

Comment: No worries. have fun :)